# Send AJAX get request

Tags: php, jquery

I just started to study AJAX and I already have some trouble.
I created database and table `users` with `id, name, email` fields.
Then I created php file `db.php` for connection with the database

```
<?php 
$dblocation = "localhost";
$dbname = "test5";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpasswd = "";

$dbcnx = @mysql_connect($dblocation, $dbuser, $dbpasswd);
if (!$dbcnx) {
    exit ( "<p>Error.</p>" );
}

if ( ! @mysql_select_db($dbname, $dbcnx)) {
    exit ( "<p>Error.</p>" );
}
?>
```

,created file `get-user.php` to return an answer for ajax-request

```
<?php
include ("db.php"); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, email FROM users WHERE id='$id'", $dbcnx);
return $result;
?>
```

And this is my `index.php` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>index</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#button-1').on('click', function () {
                    var id = $('#user-id').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'get-user.php',
                        datatype: "html",
                        data: id,
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <input name="id" id="user-id" type="text" size="15" />
        <button id="button-1">Get data</button>
</html>
```

I would like to input the number, click button and get information about user from database, but I get only empty alert. How to make it work?
Sorry for asking, I'm just newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These changes are require:

Ajax: `data: id,` to `data: "{id : id},`
PHP: `return $result;` to `echo $result;`
PHP & MySQL:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, email FROM users WHERE id='$id'", $dbcnx);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
return $result[0] . ";" . $row[1];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help! I changed code, but I didn't get right data about user, I get some strange alert and I don't understand what does in mean?  http://i.stack.imgur.com/tQtmV.png Can you explain me, please, what's the problem?

Comment: @truslivii.lev, The problem is that you extract a resource from the MySQL but doesn't abstract it to a form the AJAX Call can understand it. You should add before the `return` command the following code i edited.

Comment: Can you explain me please what I need to add in my code to make it work?

Comment: I found the answer! Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: @truslivii.lev, Did my new edited answer helped you ? If so mark it as "Accepted Answer"

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to pass the parameters is this

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'get-user.php',
        datatype: "html",
        data: { id: id },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

In the `php` return the value like this

```
<?php
include ("db.php"); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, email FROM users WHERE id='$id'", $dbcnx);
$fetch=mysql_fetch_array($result);
return $fetch["email"];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help! I changed code, but I didn't get right data about user, I get some strange alert and I don't understand what does in mean?  http://i.stack.imgur.com/tQtmV.png Can you explain me, please, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**Javascript:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'get-user.php',
    datatype: "html",
    data: {id:id},
    success: function (data) {
          alert(data);
       }
  });
```

**in get-user.php:**

```
<?php        
  if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        include ("db.php"); 
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        ....
  }
?>
```

**Note:** Use mysqli_* functions or PDO instead of mysql_* functions(deprecated)

Comment: mysql_query will not prevent sql injection

Answer (score 1):

You are very close, but there are a few things you need to change.

first inside of your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'get-user.php',
    datatype: "html",
    data: {'id': id},
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

notice the change in the `data` option.

Second, inside your `get-user.php` you refer to the value using `$_GET['id']`.

Finally, instead of `return` you want to `echo` the response.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help! I changed code, but I didn't get right data about user, I get some strange alert and I don't understand what does in mean?  http://i.stack.imgur.com/tQtmV.png Can you explain me, please, what's the problem?

Comment: you need to use `mysql_fetch_row` on `$result`. Look at this example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

Answer (score 1):

Ajax code

```
data: {id: id};
```

php code

use [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of mysql_query, the code you use on `mysql_query` its not prevent sql injection.

```
include ("db.php"); 

$id = $_GET['id'];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT name, email FROM users WHERE id = :id');
$stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));
$result = $stmt->get_result();

echo $result;
```

or use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT name, email FROM users WHERE id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('id', $id);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

echo $result;
```